# Как правильно написать функцию JS each

Tags: javascript

Есть вот такой
JS

```
 prepareData: function()
                {
                    $('.like-button').each(function(index, el) {
                        postLoader.postButtons[$(el).attr('id')] = 
                          $(el).data('id');
                    });
                },

                events: function()
                {

                    $('body').on('click', '.like-button', function(event) {

                        var key = $(this).attr('id');

                        var id = postLoader.postButtons[key];
                        var classlike = $(this);
                        postLoader.send(id,classlike);
                    });

                },
```

Проблема в то, что если загрузить данные аяксом то это функция не работает пишет, что id `undefined` но если загрузить страницу уже готовым то id передает. С кнопкой получилось, изменил
ЭТО

```
$('.like-button').on('click', function(event)
```

на

`$('body').on('click', '.like-button', function(event)`

Попробовал сделать тоже самое для `each` но не получилось. Надеюсь на вашу помощь и возможно кто-то знает альтернативу.

```
$('body').each('.like-button', function(index, el) {
     postLoader.postButtons[$(el).attr('id')] = $(el).data('id');
 });
```

Comment: попробуйте делегирование

Comment: После того как посты загрузились через ajax, вызывайте функцию prepareData()

Comment: Актуально до сих пор